# Slow script in IE7 - fastest jquery selector

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer-7

```
$.each(data, function (i, val) {
                        $(':checkbox.' + i).prop('checked', (val == 1 ? true : false));
                        $(':text.' + i + ', select.' + i).val(val);
                    });
```

data is a JSON-object. IE7 cries about a slow script when i run this. Im mapping values from the json object to the classname, "i". Is there any way to make this selector run faster? The code works, but the speed of iterating thorugh every element must be faster to get rid of the ie7 slow script message. Thanks

Comment: I think we shoud make some consideration on the markup. Probably there's a way to optimize that before the script. Could you also provide a snippet of your html?

Comment: Have you identified where the slow came from? Could be from the loop $.each, or from one of your selectors... Have an online page running the script?

Comment: @BorisDelormas Its the selectors. Its not a public page.

Comment: use context with that kind of selector $(':checked', $context), and cache if you reuse (in a each for exemple...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use pseudo selectors without a container or narrowed context, they're slow and particularly bad in IE7 or IE8 compat mode in my experience.

Switch the `$(":etc")` syntax with `$("#container").find("input:text")` and try replacing the $.each with a traditional for loop (Assuming the $.each is iterating a lot of things, otherwise the impact is negligable)

cache the container outside the loop too.

```
var $container = $("#container");
$.each (etc, function(i) {
      var a = $container.find("input:text");
      // do more stuff
}
```

Some markup might provide me with an opportunity to be a little more specific

Comment: Thanks, is there any difference between $container.find('.blah') VS the selector $('.container .blah')?

Comment: No difference unless you use your selector several times. In this case you should use $container

Comment: not entirely true. if you have a document with hundreds of DOM nodes, having to look for class 'container' in each of them can be very expensive. IE7 is particularly bad at that (as is the iPad, incidentally). multiple class names is probably the most expensive slector you can have.

Answer (score 0):

Some tips:

- `.prop()` is in general slower than `.attr()`
- narrow your selectors: "`:checkbox`" and "`:text`" only applies to inputs

  $('input:checkbox.'+i).attr('checked', Boolean(val));
  $('input:text.'+i+', select.'+i).val(val);

Answer (score 0):

Can you narrow it down to a parent? I.e., are these elements inside a form, a div, etc you can start from?

```
var $memoized_form = $( 'form#the_form' );

$.each(data, function (i, val) {
    $memoized_form.find( 'input:checkbox.' + i ).prop('checked', (val == 1 ? true : false));
    $memoized_form.find( 'input:text.' + i + ', select.' + i).val(val);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any difference between $container.find('.blah') VS the selector $('.container .blah')?

Comment: yes, $('.container .blah') means that jQuery first has to look at EVERY node to see if it is of class 'container' and then it has to check whether it has children of class blah. some more modern browser have a native getElementsByClassName, but IE7 is not one of them